# Can onSaveInstanceState() be called manually?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to save and retrieve my `Activity`'s `onSaveInstanceState()` when clicking the back button. I have read that by default it is not saved because it is assumed that the user is done with the `Activity` when clicking back. However, in my app, this is not the case and I would like to call `onSaveInstanceState()` from within:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It is, however, saved on screen rotation. This I have read is also default behaviour.

I have spent a couple of days trying to hack this, but I'm just not getting anywhere.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is for surviving config changes and process death, it's not for persisting your stuff to disk and so on. To be honest, the only place where that is a thing is `onStop()` combined with `if(isFinishing())` (but your app can be terminated even if your Activity never finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to save and retrieve my activities savedInstanceState when clicking the back button. I have read that by default it is not saved because it is assumed that the user is done with the activity when clicking back.

All is correct. Moreover, in this case *Android* assumes the app is no longer needed for user so it can safely terminate the app process.

> Can saveInstanceSate be called manually?

Of course. The [method is `protected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). But it doesn't make sense as per your requirement. In your case, even though the "manual" `Bundle` you pass as a method parameter will be saved by the system, the data residing in RAM will be immediately vanished with the app process itself due to the back press.

> It is, however, saved on screen rotation.

Also is correct. In this case *Android* assumes the app is still in use, so it cares (partially) for restoring its state for you.

> However, in my app, this is not the case and I would like to saveInstanceState from within `onBackPressed()`.

I doubt you should struggle the OS idiom. *Android* provides you alternative options to restore the app state (so a user "thought" he/she got back to your app exactly at the point it was left), e.g. `SharedPreferences`, database, internal storage etc. I recommend to stick the OS idioms.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have considered Shared Preferences for some of the String based items. However, the real issue is that one of my activities contains a TabLayout with RecyclerView fragments. Each time it is exited and opened again, there is a 1 to 2 second delay while the fragments are re-created. It takes away from the snappiness of the navigation. This is what I am specifically trying to get around. Trouble is, I don't know how to store a TabLayout. I have been focusing on savedInstanceState as there is no such delay on rotate. However, as you point out, this is not going help.

Comment: @Christopher Mills, you can't store `TabLayout ` either in `Bundle` nor `SharedPreferences` because it does not implement `Serializable` interface. You should stick the Android app lifecycle paradigm as all other developers do. If possible, show a loading indicator _"while the fragments are re-created"_.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend persisting data of this nature and scenario using SharedPreferences. By this, the work of savedInstanceState() is manually done. This data survive untimely app death, configuration change etc.

Comment: Some state doesn't need to survive when you force quit the app, though.